# Python Error IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

```
import requests, sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.crossoutdb.com/");

s=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml' );

it=s.find(id="ItemTable").find("tbody");

f=open("market.csv", "w")

f.write("item,faction,type,popularity,sell_price,sell_offers,buy_price,buy_ordes,margin\n")

 for item in it.find_all("tr"):
 title=item.find(class_="item-title ").text.strip();

   print(data);
   data=item.contents[1].text.strip().split("\n")
   title=data[0];
   faction=data[1];
   type=data[2];

            rareity=item.contents[3].text.strip()
            popularity = item.contents[5].text.strip();
            sell_price = item.contents[7].text.strip();
            sell_offers = item.contents[9].text.strip();
            buy_price = item.contents[11].text.strip();
            buy_orders= item.contents[13].text.strip();
            margin = item.contents[15].text.strip();

x="\"{}\",{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}\n".format( title, faction, type,popularity, sell_price, sell_offers, buy_price, buy_orders, margin);
f.write(x)
f.close()
```

> Error : Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "**************\market_dumper.py", line 19, in 
>       faction=data[14]; IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: `data` has less than 15 elements - print it out and see what's going on.

Comment: Please fix the indenting in your example code. (And get rid of all the silly semi-colons).

Answer (score 2):

You are having the

`Error : Traceback (most recent call last): File "**************\market_dumper.py", line 19, in faction=data[14]; IndexError: list index out of range`

as `data` might not contain 15 elements. If it did, this line shouldn't be throwing an error. Try `print(data)` and check if it has 15 elements or not.

Also, please edit your post and put the result of the `print()` in your post so that we can see how many elements are in `data`.